# Explosion in an open pipe

Tags: automotive-engineering

I have a design for a gasoline engine cylinder that is open at the top, closed at the bottom (a single pipe cylinder) that operates on opposed force (the pistons move lateral to the up-down direction of the pipe.  I believe it's an extremely efficient engine design that would produce -no disorganized cloud of vapor explosion-, absolutely none, but a single diamond shaped concentrated vapor burst between the two pistons, and at the top the flame profile turns into a string before disintegrating.  The description is, it says top torus, actually those are the pistons, and they're both half hemispheres.  The ring around the base of the pistons are repeated metallic X's that control the flame profile, and the cylinders move in a horizontal position laterally, not up and down as this is an opposed force design.  Here is a youtube video of an open pipe explosion: [Open Pipe Explosion #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=UG&hl=en-GB&v=2--CWLW_TvE)

My question is, since this a nonlinear explosion in an engine that should be the most efficient, how would somebody go about making the engine, or convincing an automaker to build one.  I don't have a patent on it, but I designed it.

[image: cylinder]

Comment: For a horizontally opposed piston engine, the TS3 was very interesting,  see : http://www.oldengine.org/members/diesel/rootes-listerts3/ts3.htm

Comment: I fail to see the advantage to having an open end, which would appear to release all the pressure generated (which is what drives pistons).   Can you clarify how/why this does not happen in your design?